# Need to make a a vector in R from a bunch of numbers that are separated only by a space not a comma

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix, vector

The title says it all:

I need to make a a vector in R from a bunch of numbers that are separated only by a space, not a comma. For example: 1 2 3 4 5 
Obviously manually inserting a "," in between all of them is not efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Without it, how do you expect to us to help you? Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are in a string, you can read them using `scan`, as in

```
 scan(text="1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
```